# Django, DRF, nginx, Jmeter: Sample Time becomes large even though there is no load on the CPU, etc

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, django-rest-framework, jmeter

I am using `Jmeter` to load test the `DRF`, and even though the CPU and memory are not at 100%, the throughput and response time is slow.

The `Django` + `nginx` and `Postgres` servers are separated, and both have the following specs
4CPU, 4GB memory.

nginx is using docker's `https-portal` as shown below.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  https-portal:
    image: steveltn/https-portal:1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      DOMAINS: "my.domain.com -> http://backend:8000"
      STAGE: "production"
    volumes:
      - https-portal-data:/var/lib/https-portal
      - ./nginx/uwsgi_params:/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
      - ./static:/static
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always

  backend:
    build: .
    command: uwsgi --http :8000 --module myapp.wsgi --processes 4
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - ./static:/usr/src/app/static
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .env.prod
    restart: always

volumes:
  https-portal-data:
```

Looking at the django logs, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with django, what do you think could be causing this?
`generated 8302 bytes in 29 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 7 headers in 208 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`

Setting up Jmeter:

[image]

Django + nginx server:
[image]

DB(postgres) server:
[image]

After 5 minutes of continuous loading.
[image]

If there is any other information you need, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check your application performance via [profiler tool](https://anticdent.org/profiling-wsgi-apps.html)
2. Depending on the outcome you may also want to [check Postgresql query logs and stats](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/3-ways-to-detect-slow-queries-in-postgresql/)
3. [Don't run JMeter in GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/), it might be the case you're getting false negative results because JMeter cannot send requests fast enough and/or got stuck due to garbage collection
4. Follow other [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and make sure that JMeter doesn't lack CPU, RAM, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked everything and the situation has not improved. Is it possible that `nginx` is the cause?